# Does OpenEBS support content delivery service?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, storage, openebs

Whether OpenEBS can help me to implement content delivery service (only for audio files) to replace S3?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question.

Short answer: Yes. OpenEBS is a way to for you to use Volumes in Kubernetes. To implement a Content Delivery Service you need some kind of application with a storage backend. OpenEBS allows you to be that storage backend.